# Change badge component background to custom colour dynamically within Popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a badge element that is displayed in a popover when an item in my application is clicked who's background colour is set dynamically according to the colour property of the item.

I have attempted this with the following code, however, I am unsuccessful in getting the bade to change colour.

```html
var badgeHtml = '<span class="badge badge-pill" style="background-color:'+clickedItem.colour+' !imporant">'+clickedItem.name+'</span>'
```

clickedItem.colour is a hex string value e.g. #32a852

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

I am trying to display this badge within a popover created like this:

```html
$(element).popover('dispose');
$(element).popover({
    sanitize: false,
    container: element,
    placement: 'top',
    animation: false,
    html: true,
    title: item.name + '<span class="badge badge-pill" style="background-color:'+item.colour+' !imporant;">'+item.property+'</span>',
});
$(element).popover('show');
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery ? Also you changing the adding a badge on a button click ? Can you show that code as well

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I have added in the code for where the bade is created, as you can see, I am using sanitize:false, which I thought would fix the issue, but has not

Comment: You want create a badge in the popover ? is this what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Yeah I want the badge within the popover title but with the background colour set according to the colour property of item that the user is clicking on. The popover is being displayed correctly with the badge but the background colour is not being set

Comment: I was going to highlight this typo with `t` missing in your `css` but i thought to confirm first whether thats an actually issue or not. Anyways you got the answer.

Comment: Yeah haha thanks for the comments anyway! Was a classic case of late-night coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you miswrote `!important` in your span.

Then, please find below the result of the popover you are searching, made by BS 4.

You can find all details here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

I also remove your js var from the injection of the popover as you did not provide them but I guess, you won't have any problem to replace that yourself.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    sanitize: false,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'top',
    animation: false,
    html: true,
    title: '',
    content: 'ITEM NAME <div class="badge badge-pill" style="background-color:red !important;">PROPERTY</div>',
    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header"></h3><div class="popover-body"></div></div>',
    
    })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="height:500px; width: 100%; padding-top:100px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover">Click to toggle popover</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Best regards,

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Is the background colour of the badge still white in this example and not red?

Comment: @Gecko29 It is in red. It is a "t" missing from your important, this is why he did not get the value. Enjoy and validate :-)